# Magento: Remove other shipping result when free shipping shown

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have setup the free shipping for specific product categories in magento by refering this blog post http://www.regularjen.com/archives/2010/06/11/free-shipping-on-a-single-item-in-magento/ . And its working fine. Now the issue is , Magento showing both free shipping & other shipping charges in shiiping reuslt.

How can i remove the those result ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to override the getShippingRates() method which you can find in the Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available class.

```
   public function getShippingRates()
    {
        parent::getShippingRates();

        if (isset($this->_rates['freeshipping'])) {
            $this->_rates = array('freeshipping' => $this->_rates['freeshipping']);
        }

        return $this->_rates;
    }
```